# Cannot get auto import to work for Android

Tags: android

my import class not working,

I did the following

1. file->settings->general->auto import
   -checked all the options
2. file->settings->keymap->other->auto-import
   set key map to ctrl 5 on numpad also tried ctrl p
3. file->clear cash reset.

I don't know what else to use, I'm running Windows 8.

Comment: Are you sure your missing import can be **auto**-resolved?

Comment: Eclipse or Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unistall Android and re-install it, it then worked, don't know what happen.